# vue 3 access props passed from parent component that are not defined in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

hope everything is okay.

i am used to react.js but when i try vue things were a bit different
in react it's very simple accessing props passed from parent in the child component
but in vue i must define each prop to use it.

so i was just wondering if it's possible to pass any prop and use it in the child component without defining it

## in react i can do that

```js
// parent component
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <Child anyprop="propvalue" />
  )
}
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>{JSON.stringify(props)}</p>
  )
}
```

and that would work

## in vue i can only use props if i define it like this

```js
//parent
<template>
  <Child anyprop="value" anotherprop="value"></Child>
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  anyprop: String
})
//child
<template>
  <p>{{props}}</p>
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  anyprop: String
})
</script>
```

if i do that in vue i can only see "anyprop" not the "anotherprop" i must define it in the define props block to use it

any ideas what can i do to achieve something like what react.js offers

Answer (score 1):

All data that isn't defined in `props` goes to *attributes*. Despite the name, they aren't HTML attributes and can have non-string values.

In a template they are available as `$attrs`:

```
<Child :anyprop="$attrs.anyprop" anotherprop="value"/>
```

A more common case is to pass all attributes instead of enumerating them, this is a counterpart to React `{...rest}`:

```
<Child v-bind="$attrs" anotherprop="value"/>
```

This may be not needed for root element like `Child` because [attribute fallthrough](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#fallthrough-attributes) is done by default, otherwise `inheritAttrs: false` should be used.

This requires `Child` to have `anyprop` prop declared.

In a script, attributes are available as `context.attrs` in setup function and `useAttrs` in `script setup`, they can be used to compute props for nested elements.

Comment: great answer, but what if i need to exclude some attribute like this 
```const {title, ...otherAttrs} =attrs;``` can i use otherAttrs in template

Comment: by the way ```useAttrs``` only returns html known attributes not any custom ones i have

Comment: Yes, you can, do this inside a computed and use this computed in a template. It receives any attrs, see https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9Uj1PwzAQ/SuHl6RS6gjGkCJ1Y0RiYMAMSXMpqRzb8jllqPLfOSdVCUVU8nAf7959PJ/E1jl5HFAUoqSd71wAwjC4J2W63lkf4AQeWxih9baHhKGJMsrsrKEAPe1hE/Np8oxaW3irqJmf9bq5S1YXmlfdNehnFiVkPvuxtRKPkbHM5/7cmZ2AvdNVQPYAynNxvVHiQQkoKjbu2ZizZy52yvxSJzIxd173lZMHsoZXPEW8OidIiQKmSIxNgxRsfIbgqMhzandxugNJ6/c5W9IPJnQ9SqR+XXv7RTz/gVmyBUfOwSP6tUfDI6G/xXkF/cMbaUdlRl7l51pRqMVxpJS/1p6O95+QDbadwRdvHWUwEG5D8HQlrcYALiJY2AU+fU/q5GPFSkVANRVuLhwp6xx/hNUotd2nE4GssxkoK04v5BXjN7Ce270= .